# Condition for Continuity (two variable)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I came across the following question while studying for quals.  This one is from a previous qualifier.  I have a few ideas (which I'll mention below), but am stuck on how to complete the problem.  Any help or guidance you may be able to offer would be very much appreciated.  Here is the question as it appears on the qual:

> Define:
>   $$
>   f(x,y) = 
>   \begin{cases}
>     {\Large\frac{|x|^m|y|^n}{|x|^p+|y|^q}},\; (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\ 
>     \quad\quad 0,\;\quad\quad (x,y) = (0,0)
>   \end{cases}
>   \quad\text{where } m, n, p, q >0
> $$
>
> 1. Find some necessary conditions on $m,n,p,q$ such that $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$; find some sufficient conditions on $m,n,p,q$ such that $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.
> 2. Find a necessary and sufficient condition on $m,n,p,q$ such that $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

My thoughts on this problem were to break it up into cases.  At first, I played around with $m,n,p,q$ only being in $\mathbb{N}$, hoping this would provide me with some insight.
I think I can say that if $m,n,p,q$ are all equal, that should work, as it should if either $m\geq p$ or $n\geq q$, or both.  This seems to work even for fractional values.  I feel like there is much more I am missing.
On the other hand, if I can find conditions on $m,n,p,q$ such that $f$ becomes differentiable, then that should also force $f$ to be continuous. Without forcing differentiability, I am guessing there will be many cases to consider (i.e., when $x,y$ are positive, negative, etc.).

I am just a bit lost on how to proceed.  I am having trouble ironing out the details.  Thank you very much for any help you can offer.

Comment: How about computing the partials and seeing when they exist and are continuous (for sufficiency), ignoring the absolute values first, of course, or considering two cases when $x,y$ have different signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claim: $f(x,y) \to 0 \iff m/p + n/q >1.$

Proof: We only need to work in the open first quadrant. Note the following:

$$ (x_n,y_n) \to (0,0) \iff ((x_n)^{1/p},(y_n)^{1/q}) \to (0,0).$$

This tells us that as $(x,y) \to (0,0), f(x,y)\to 0 \iff f(x^{1/p},y^{1/q})\to 0.$

Now

$$f(x^{1/p},y^{1/q}) = \frac{x^{m/p}y^{n/q}}{x+y}.$$

So let's look at the situation of

$$g(x,y) = \frac{x^ay^b}{x+y}.$$

I'll show $g(x,y) \to 0 \iff a+b>1,$ which will prove the claim. Suppose $a+b>1.$ Then

$$g(x,y) = y^{b-(1-a)}\frac{x^ay^{1-a}}{x+y}.$$

By convexity, the fraction on the right is $\le 1.$ Hence $g(x,y)\le y^{b-(1-a)}\to 0.$ Suppose $a+b=1.$ Then

$$g(x,x) = \frac{x}{x+x} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Thus $g(x,y) \not \to 0.$ Suppose $a+b<1.$ Then

$$g(x,x) = x^{b-(1-a)}\frac{x}{x+x} = x^{b-(1-a)}\frac{1}{2} \to \infty,$$

which of course implies $g(x,y) \not \to 0.$That does it.

Comment: Hi, I've revised my answer,

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to mark your answer as useful to me.  Thank you very much for your help.  I think this clears it up for me.